# MVC Javascript Serialization Format

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, serialization

I am using `@(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.DateSlotModel)))` in my view and it causing a javascript error because it produces the following when in the script block:

```
var initialData = [{&quot;DateID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;DateValue&quot;:&quot;4/1/2011&quot;}]);
```

What do I need to do to get the output to be formated as follows?

```
[{"DateID":"1","DateValue":"4/1/2011"}]
```

Controller Code:

```
jobmodel.DateSlotModel = from d in eventRepository.GetEventDates(eventid)
                         select new ScheduleDateSlotViewModel
                         {
                             DateID = d.DateID.ToString(),
                             DateValue = d.DateValue.ToShortDateString()
                         };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
 var InitialData = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.DateSlotModel)))
```

Comment: How can you use JavaScriptSerializer without fully qualifying it with System.Web.Script.Serialization?